# Особенности работы np.setdiff1d

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, словари, обработка-данных

Есть [фрейм данных](https://www.dropbox.com/s/owoht7f65rra8jm/dict?dl=0) с названием `frame` формата:

```
   player_id
0   2560866
1   2560866
2   2560866
3   2560866
4   2552478
```

и [словарь](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dcezsaelpwrb53/frame_a.csv?dl=0) с названием `pi` формата:

```
{
2563986: 10892,
2558091: 6479,
2563967: 10783,
2536340: 3766,
2560757: 4657,
2555224: 6515,
2562699: 6548,
}
```

Хочу найти значения из фрейма данных, которые отсутсвуют в словаре в виде ключей.

Использую разницу множеств:

```
set(frame['player_id'].unique()) - set(pi.keys())
```

Получаю корректный ответ:

```
set()
```

Использую `np.setdiff1d` :

```
np.setdiff1d(frame['player_id'].unique(), pi.keys())
```

Получаю:

```
array([2495143, 2536340, 2541199, 2552478, 2552487, 2555224, 2558091,
       2560735, 2560757, 2560866, 2562699, 2563967, 2563986])
```

Почему так происходит? В чем заключается особенность поведения numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

думаю проблема в том, что Numpy не понимает тип `dict_keys`.

Попробуйте так:

```
In [109]: np.setdiff1d(frame['player_id'].unique(), list(pi.keys()))
Out[109]: array([2552478, 2560866])

In [110]: set(frame['player_id'].unique()) - set(pi.keys())
Out[110]: {2552478, 2560866}
```